# How can I have a TextBox style with properties of other TextBox style

Tags: wpf, styles

I made an TextBox style but now i need some differences for example an other corner radius.

This is my default style:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBoxBase}">
                    <Border
                        CornerRadius="10"
                        Padding="2"
                        Background="{DynamicResource DefaultItemBGBrush}"
                        BorderBrush="#C2C2C2"
                        BorderThickness="1" >
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="0" x:Name="PART_ContentHost" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#8D8D8D"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Now i want some TextBoxes with the same properties but for example with CornerRadius="10,10,0,0" and one with CornerRadius="0,0,10,10" and so on.

Is it possible to create an new style with a special CornerRadius and take the other properties from my default TextBox? I dont want to make 10 styles like my default one with just an other corner radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a **CustomControl** (which inherits from TextBox) where you can create a **DependencyProperty** called CornerRadius, and then in your style, have access to the dependency property. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx) for a tutorial.

```
public System.Windows.CornerRadius CornerRadius
    {
        get { return (System.Windows.CornerRadius)GetValue(CornerRadiusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CornerRadiusProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for CornerRadius.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CornerRadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CornerRadius", typeof(System.Windows.CornerRadius), typeof(YourControlClass), new PropertyMetadata(10));
```

Comment: Did you try it? `Border.CornerRadius` is of a `System.Windows.CornerRadius` type and `Border.BorderThickness` is of `System.Windows.Thickness` type

Comment: My bad, I will edit the post to reflect the custom control solution.

Comment: Thank you.
There is no xaml-only solution for this, right?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. As @dkozl pointed out, there are no properties on the TextBox that will allow you to 'sacrafice' and use the property as a CornerRadius.